# Есть ли готовые решения для создания своего браузера Chromium на Visual C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Хочется узнать существуют ли готовые проекты, фреймворки, контролы для создания своего браузера на базе Chromium в Visual C# .NET?
Знаю о существовании cefsharp, но это лишь движок. А хотелось бы реализовать приближенную копию браузера Chrome последних версий с современной стилистикой вкладок.
Буду очень благодарен за любые подсказки, наводки или ссылки :)

Comment: `Знаю о существовании cefsharp, но это лишь движок` Это не движок, а обертка над Chromium.

Comment: @ГеннадийП вы правы) просто имею ввиду нет UI для управления. Т.е. вкладки которые можно перемещать и отделять от окна.
Нашел EasyTabs но там давно не было обновлений. Может думал есть что то актуальное)